# testng tasks running parallely on different JVMs

Tags: java, xml, maven, ant, testng

I have a need to start the testng classes in parallel and in two different JVM instances. I am trying to use ant parallel task to achieve this but not successful. With the below block it starts two testng tasks sequentially and not in parallel. Can you please help me fix this?

```xml
<parallel threadCount="1">
   <testng classpathref="maven.test.classpath" outputdir="target/first">
      <classfileset dir="build">
         <include name="**/TestX.class" />
      </classfileset>
      <jvmarg line="${java.args}" />
      <jvmarg line="${run.args}" />
   </testng>
   <testng classpathref="maven.test.classpath" outputdir="target/second">
      <classfileset dir="build">
         <include name="**/TestY.class" />
      </classfileset>
      <jvmarg line="${java.args}" />
      <jvmarg line="${run.args}" />
   </testng>
</parallel>
```

Comment: Do you want to try and see by increasing `threadCount` attribute value?

Comment: nope, that didnt work either :(

Comment: May be you can check sample [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-the-parallel-task.html)

Comment: Have already checked that and in fact it those specific examples in the link work too. The issue I find is parallel mode with testng tasks (note: testng task runs in a different vm)

Answer (score 0):

According to TestNG task documentation it always runs in fork mode (read in separate JVM from Ant). So, I think `threadCount="1"` might be the reason of sequential execution.

Comment: thanks for the reply, unfortunately that has no impact!